# Nested promises and how to get around em

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using a promise to get some JSON from a URL. The JSON that is returned includes a list of new URLs that return JSON. My current implementation is failing due to the nested promises.

**I need to do the following:**

1. request parent JSON url
2. request each of the child JSON urls
3. After each child promise returns JSON, I need to do some stuff with the child's JSON and the parent JSON.

**I am getting the following error.**

`Warning: a promise was created in a handler at main.development.js:661:61 but was not returned from it`

**Boiled down version of my code:**

```js
myPromise(url)
  .then(response => {
    // process the data into an array of items
   items.forEach(item => {
      myPromise(item.url)
        .then(response2 => {
          // Do a thing here with data from response and response2
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Array forEach is not Promise aware.. There is `promise.all`, But if say you use something like the Bluebird promises, it has the `promise.map` that is more flexible than `promise.all`

Comment: Thanks Keith. I am using request-promise which uses Bluebird, so that's good! That said, I've taken a look at the Promise.map bluebird documentation and not quite sure how to use it to accomplish what I need. Do you have any articles or examples handy that you could link me to?

Comment: The map works pretty much like a normal javascript map, but can handle promises.. I'll do a copy of you code, and paste as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've done your example, using Bluebird map.

I've also added the concurrency option, this is very handy.. Leaving out, will just work a bit like promise.all, and putting a value of 1, would be were you want to do all the promises in series..

```js
myPromise(url)
  .then(response => {
    // process the data into an array of items
   return Promise.map(items, item => {
     return myPromise(item.url)
        .then(response2 => {
          // Do a thing here with data from response and response2
        });
    }, {concurrency:10});  //lets do a max of 10 promises at a time.
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You error is actually just a warning. It is there for good reason; a common mistake is doing something like this

```
myPromise(url)
    .then(response => {
        somethingElseAsync(response);        
    })
    .then(myCallback);
```

and expecting `myCallback` to be invoked after `somethingElseAsync` has finished work. As far as I can tell, this is not your case, since you are not collecting the results of your child promises.

To suppress the warning, you can follow [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40433829/1391671). As a bonus, you can tack another promise onto your chain which will resolve when all child promises have resolved.

As an alternative to `Promise.map`, if you are okay with spawning all child tasks simultaneously, you can get away with `Promise.all`, like this:

```
myPromise(url).then(response => {
    return Promise.all(items.map(item => {
        return myPromise(item.url).then(response2 => {
            // handle response and response2, return some result
            return result;
        });
    }));
}).then(results => {
    //    ^^^ an array of results returned from child promise callbacks
}).catch(error => {
    // either the parent promise or one of the child promises has rejected
});
```